# Finding white pixels on monitor in camera image

Tags: c++, image-processing, statistics

I have a camera pointed at a monitor displaying a line of white pixels. I get an array of byte values back from the camera. The area of the camera's view is larger than the space taken up by the monitor. I need to find out where on the camera image the white monitor pixels appear.  See the sample image below.[image: Sample Image]

I need to improve my algorithm so that it is more robust in varying lighting conditions. Specifically, I need to improve the step where I determine the value threshold for what are considered potential white pixels. After determining what are likely my white pixels, I find the largest neighborhood to determine my final white values.

I also tried counting the N pixels with the highest values and considering the lowest value of the N pixels as white. This worked fairly well in some conditions, but it stopped working when the room got slightly darker. I can tweak N to work in any lighting condition, but I would prefer not to have to provide any parameters manually. I am experimenting with using percentiles now, but it is running quite slow since the data set is very large.

Here's one of the methods that works decently, but the parameters have to be tweaked in different lighting conditions.

```
std::multiset<uint8_t> maxPixelValues;
for(unsigned i = 0; i < width; ++i)
{
    for(unsigned j = 0; j <height; ++j)
    {
        uint8_t pixelValue = buffer[j * width + i];
        if(maxPixelValues.size() < topPixelCount)
        {
            maxPixelValues.insert(pixelValue);
        }
        else
        {
            auto minimumValuePosition = maxPixelValues.begin();
            if(pixelValue > *minimumValuePosition)
            {
                maxPixelValues.erase(minimumValuePosition);
                maxPixelValues.insert(pixelValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
return *maxPixelValues.begin();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you might want to threshold at one standard deviation above the mean to get rid of the darker parts of the screen. Then you can take advantage of the fact that the line is quite thin compared to some of the brighter area in the background and also far away from other bright areas thanks to the edge of the screen.

Pseudocode:

```
mask=threshold(img, mean(img)+stdev(img))
toignore=dilate(mask,3,3) 
toignore=erode(toignore,4,4) 
toignore=dilate(toignoe,3,3)
mask=mask &! toignore
```

1. Thresholding at mean+sd:
   [image: Mask thresholded at mean+sd]
2. Dilation:
   [image: Dilation]
3. Erosion with slightly bigger kernel to remove 1px thin objects (such as the line), but keep pixels that are near other bright ones
   [image: Erosion]
4. Dilation to add a margin smaller than the screen border:
   [image: Dilation again]
5. Thresholded mask from 1 with toignore from 4 excluded:
   [image: Mask with dilated/eroded/dilated stuff ignored]

There are a few stray pixels left, but you can probably do a hough transform at this point.

Comment: This is great, thank you! I already look at the size of the pixel neighborhoods and eliminate all but the largest, which should take care of the strays. I will try implementing this tomorrow and let you know how it goes. It was taking a while to compute the mean and standard deviation, but I think I can just compute the thresholds once rather than on each frame to make up for the long processing time.

Comment: Computing mean and SD shouldn't take that long. You can compute them in one pass with [Welford's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Online_algorithm). It took me about 0.02 s including reading/writing the image.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. I'm using OpenCV, which has mean and standard deviation functions which also may be faster than what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hough transform to find lines on an image: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform

Here is the openCV api: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html

Comment: I tried something similar,  but the problem is that I pick up other lines like the edge of the monitor. I would still have to have a threshold to tell which lines are on the monitor and which are other things.

Comment: If you roughly know the area that you are covering, you can reject outliers.

Comment: This is the process I use to determine the area I'm covering. This is part of a calibration sequence.

Comment: If you know the distribution of black pixels around the detected line, you can neglect other. For example, you can manually annotate several lines you are looking and calculate some sort of statistics. During the calibration time, you can neglect all those lines that do not fit this statistics.